# Is MySQL community server local or server hosted

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to setup a server for my database but I'm confused. Is MySQL community server stored on the computer or on MySQL servers? I can't find a definitive answer and I'm confused because when I set up an account on the Community server for some reason I had to install it and it didn't give me server credentials like Hostname or Username.

EDIT: I saw a post saying to use the command line but whenever I click to open it flashes and closes.

Comment: You can install versions of MySQL on your own server, including on your own local computer (acting as a localhost server).

Comment: *"I saw a post saying to use the command line but whenever I click to open it flashes and closes."* - You would need to provide more information.  (What post?  What did you click on?  What flashed and closed?  What is your OS? Etcetera.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is MySQL community server stored on the computer or on MySQL servers

No one would store your data for free. If you install MySQL in a computer, data will be stored in that computer.

The default username is "root" and password is "" (nothing)

I hope you are using linux. If so, after installing MySQL, go to terminal and run the command 'mysql -u root -p' then press enter and again press enter.

If you are using Mac, then SequelPro is a good choice if you need User Interface.

For windows and linux, you can try SqlEctron as an alternative to command line.

Comment: I'm using windows and I thought MySQL Community Server was opensource community sponcored

Comment: @user9391457 you have access to a very powerful database system for free, isn't that enough?